# Split NSAttributedString into Image + NSString

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsstring, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

I have an `NSAttributedString` that can contain 3 different things :

- Just an image. (an attachment)
- Just Text
- An image followed by text  (/!\ not the other way around, never).

I'm trying to "scan" that object to know if I have an image or text, and if there is an image, if there is text afterwards.

I'm not comfortable with using the enumeration and range parameters ; the documentation didn't really help me understand how to make this work.

How would you achieve this ?

- Extract image if there is one
- Extract string if there is one (either alone or after the image).

The only code I have now is from another SO post that was kind of helpful if there was only an image.

```
 NSAttributedString *currentString = self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.attributedText;
 __block UIImage *currentImage = nil;    
    [currentString enumerateAttribute:NSAttachmentAttributeName
                                 inRange:NSMakeRange(0, [currentString length])
                                 options:0
                              usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop)
                              {
                                  if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSTextAttachment class]])
                                  {
                                      NSTextAttachment *attachment = (NSTextAttachment *)value;
                                      UIImage *image = nil;
                                      if ([attachment image])
                                          image = [attachment image];
                                      else
                                          image = [attachment imageForBounds:[attachment bounds]
                                                               textContainer:nil
                                                              characterIndex:range.location];

                                      if (image)
                                          currentImage = image;
                                  }
                              }];
```

Comment: Check if `[currentString string]` doesn't return you only the text even if there is an image. If so, you'll have the text, and you have already the code to get the image (seems to be my code btw).

Comment: That didn't do the trick apparently :(

Comment: Keep the range of the image found, and use instead a `NSMutableAttributedString`, and you can use `deleteCharactersInRange:` to remove the image in that range.

Comment: Hmm Mutable strings.. that's smart, let me give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to keep the same logic, but using a `NSMutableAttributedString` instead of a `NSAttributedString`, keep the `NSRange` of the image, and delete it.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *currentString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.attributedText];
__block UIImage *currentImage = nil;    
__block NSRange imageRange;
[currentString enumerateAttribute:NSAttachmentAttributeName
                                 inRange:NSMakeRange(0, [currentString length])
                                 options:0
                              usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop)
                              {
                                  if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSTextAttachment class]])
                                  {
                                      NSTextAttachment *attachment = (NSTextAttachment *)value;
                                      UIImage *image = nil;
                                      if ([attachment image])
                                          image = [attachment image];
                                      else
                                          image = [attachment imageForBounds:[attachment bounds]
                                                               textContainer:nil
                                                              characterIndex:range.location];

                                      if (image)
                                      {
                                          currentImage = image;
                                          imageRange = range;
                                      }
                                  }
                              }];

NSString *text = @"";
if (image)
{
    text = [[currentString deleteCharactersInRange:imageRange] string];
}

if ([text length] > 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Found Text: %@", text);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Did Found Text");
}


NSLog(image?@"Found Image";@"Did NOT found image");
```

Comment: Hey man, I've tried that when you first commented it but for some reason, the returned NSRange object in the block is null :( What could cause that? (I logged it straight after the first curly brace and its null)

Comment: I'm logging the "range" object, not the imageRange object. I'm basically assigning nothing to my __block varialbe. So no, it didn't help :P

Comment: Actually I missed something it's not null, its just logging null. The range is 0,1 which is odd because my image was (in my testing) in the middle of the text